# Error in the computation of PSF?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, transfer-function

I am in trouble computing a PSF of an optical system in optical turbulence.

**Background**

The optical transfer function (OTF) for an imaging system in optical turbulence can be modeled as the product of the atmospheric OTF and the diffraction OTF:
\begin{align}
H(\rho)=H_{\text{atm}}(\rho)H_{\text{dif}}(\rho)
\end{align}
Note that the OTFs are circularly symmetric in the frequency domain, and they are functions of $\rho=\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2}$, where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the spatial frequencies.

- The atmospheric OTF is given by
  \begin{align}
  H_{\text{atm}}(\rho) = \exp\left\{-3.44\left(\frac{\lambda\ell\rho}{r_0}\right)^{5/3}\left[1-\alpha\left(\frac{\lambda\ell\rho}{D}\right)^{1/3}\right] \right\}
  \end{align}
  where $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $\ell$ is the camera focal length, $r_0$ is the Fried parameter, and $D$ is the aperture diameter. The parameter $\alpha$ is used to model the different behavior of the OTF according to the different exposure time. When $\alpha=0$, it models a long exposure, and when $\alpha=1$, it models a short exposure.
- The diffraction OTF is given by
  \begin{align}
  H_{\text{dif}} = \begin{cases}
  \frac{2}{\pi}\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2\rho_c}\right)-\frac{\rho}{2\rho_c}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\rho}{2\rho_c}\right)^2}\right] & \rho\leq \rho_c\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  \end{align}
  where $\rho_c$ is the cut-off frequency given by $\rho_c = D/(\lambda \ell)$.

Finally, a point spread function (PSF) is computed by the inverse-Fourier transform of the overall OTF:
\begin{align}
   h = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(H)
\end{align}

**Simulation**

I simply want to visualize the cross-sections of the PSFs for $\alpha = 0, 1$ but I cannot reproduce the results in a paper for some reason. Below is the comparison of the results:

[image]

I see a good agreement in the results for $\alpha =0$ but not for $\alpha=1$. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? I attached my Matlab code below.

```
clear all; 

% Unit conversion parameters 
nm2m    = 1e-9; 
m2um    = 1e+6; 

% Parameters 
D       = 0.2034;       % [m], diameter of camera aperture 
fl      = 1.2;          % [m], focal length 
wvl     = 525*nm2m;     % [m], central wavelength
fn      = fl/D;         % f-number 
rho_c   = 1/(wvl*fn);   % [Hz] optical cut-off frequency 
delta_f = 1/(2*rho_c);  % [m], Nyquist pixel spacing 
r0      = 0.0478;       % [m], Coherence length 

% Sampling grid 
N       = 1024;                 % Number of sampling points 
delta   = delta_f/2;            % Grid spacing (spatial domain) 
n_vec   = -N/2 : 1 : N/2-1; 
df      = 1 / (N*delta);        % Grid spacing (frequency domain) 
[fX,fY] = meshgrid(n_vec*df);   % Sampling grid (frequency domain)
[~,rho] = cart2pol(fX, fY);
mask    = circ(fX, fY, 2*rho_c); 

% Diffraction-limited OTF 
rho_n = rho/(2*rho_c); 
Hdif = (2/pi)*(acos(rho_n)-rho_n.*sqrt(1-rho_n.^2)); 

figure;
cc = 0; 
for alpha = [0 1]
    cc = cc + 1; 
    % Atmospheric OTF 
    % (alpha = 0 -> long exposure, alpha = 1 -> short exposure) 
    numer = wvl*fl*rho; 
    term1 = -3.44*(numer/r0).^(5/3); 
    term2 = 1-alpha*(numer/D).^(1/3); 
    term_all = term1.*term2; 
    Hatm  = exp(term_all); 
    Hatm  = Hatm.*mask; 
    % Overall OTF 
    Hall = Hatm .* Hdif; 
    % PSF (theory)
    PSF = ift2(Hall, df); 
    PSF = abs(PSF); 
    PSF = PSF/max(max(PSF)); 
    PSF_slice = PSF(N/2+1, :); 
    % Plot 
    subplot(2,2,cc); 
    x_seq = delta*n_vec; 
    plot(x_seq/delta_f, PSF_slice), grid on; xlim([-30,30]); 
    xlabel('x (Nyquist pixels)'); ylabel('h(x,0)'); 
end

function g = ift2(G, delta_f)
    % Function to compute 2D discrete Fourier transform
    N = size(G,1);
    g = ifftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(G))) * (N * delta_f)^2;
end

function z = circ(x, y, D)
    % Circular function
    r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
    z = double(r<D/2);
    z(r==D/2) = 0.5;
end
```